# How to avoid count - last blank page number in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

> I'm designing multiple customers bill report in crystal report with Two pages (front and back).
>
> Each customer has 2,4,6 records, the report will printed front and back then Page number comes like (1 of 2, 2 of 2).
>   If one customer has 3, 5 records. The last back page is blank. Page number comes like (1 of 4, 2 of 4).
>
> But here i need (1 of 3, 2 of 3). The last blank page count will avoid.
>
> Please help this solution. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: There are no crystal-report built-in functions that count pages skipping blank pages.If you have blank pages you should consider editing the report to either avoid the blank page or in the report formula that shows the page substract the pages you want (and display nothing on the pages you dont want).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula, instead of Page N of M

```
If int(TotalPageCount / 2)  = (TotalPageCount / 2) Then  PageNofM 
Else
If PageNumber=TotalPageCount Then "" 
Else 
"Page "+Cstr(PageNumber) + " of "+ Cstr(TotalPageCount-1)
```